# Tikz fading not properly working on textures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to include a little tikz figure that shows fading between two textures. In fact, my code is perfectly working on the embed PDF reader, but produces different render on other readers.

[image]

*Embed PDF viewer*

[image]

*Linux document viewer*

[image]

*Firefox PDF viewer*

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\path (0,100);

\fill[pattern=checkerboard light gray] (140,0) rectangle (460,100);
\fill[pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=black!60!white,path fading=west] (140,0) rectangle (460,100);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any idea where this bug could come from ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is normal. PDF viewers don't have standards implemented the same way hence most viewers  don't agree on the newer PDF objects such as shadings and fadings.

Comment: See the relevant section on transparency in the pgf manual. There is not really a remedy, but you may try "reduce transparency" or similar options in a pdf reader.

Comment: Sometimes, if you fiddle, you find that an alternative method of producing a similar enough result works better in the viewers you need it to. This is really a matter of trial-and-error, though, especially since viewers get updated all the time. Firefox's PDF viewer is especially inept, though, so I just ignore things not working in that one as there's so much it screws up.